# How do you resize a part in PSpice?

Tags: simulation, software, eda

I have a number of parts that I want to re-size so as to fit on paper. How would you resize a part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah you can't really re-size a part unless you open up the part itself and move some pins around and redraw it to be smaller.  I assume you were  wanting to scale it instead of doing all that.  What you could do is go under options, schematic page properties, and then choose a larger page size.